# MariaDB c connector for OSX

Tags: c, macos, client, mariadb

i was wondering if the [MariaDB native client library](https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-native/1.0.0/) is also available for OSX.
I did not find any evidence of this after searching the net.
So i checked out the sources and tried to compile it myself. And as you can guess it didn't work.
I got the error following message while running 'make':

[image: error message when calling make]

Sorry for posting an image, but pasting this error message as text really looked ugly.
Has anyone some hints for me, on how to get this working?
Many thanks in advance.
Greetings, -chris-

Comment: Paste it as text, really. And then select it and press the `{}` button which formats it as code.

Comment: That's not working. I really tried this, and the layout of the text became a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed in rev. 66

You can obtain the source code from the bazaar repository: bzr branch lp:mariadb-native-client

Comment: Were you able to get the client library to compile? I followed the `bzr branch lp:mariadb-native-client` step, ran cmake, then make, but I'm running into quite a few build errors.